# Python pandas split value in row evenly across all duplicated ID's

Tags: python, pandas

Kind of stuck on this so hopefully someone can help. Generally I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
           "id": [1,1,1,4,5,5,7],
            "value": [100, 100, 100, 45, 3, 3, 42]
           })
```

what I want to do is for each duplicate ID is split the value evenly for each row and make a new variable that tracks how much that was split. So my ideal output is something like this

```
id  value   value2      people
1   100     33.333333   0.333333
1   100     33.333333   0.333333
1   100     33.333333   0.333333
4   45      45.000000   1
5   3       1.500000    0.500000
5   3       1.500000    0.500000
7   42      42.000000   1
```

I've gotten value 2 by doing this:

```
df['value2'] = df.groupby(['id'])['value'].apply(lambda x: x / len(x))
```

but not having luck with the people column :( I originally tried:

```
df['people'] = df.groupby(['id']).apply(lambda x: 1. / len(x))
```

which was close, but missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to specific a single column of the groupby (doesn't matter which one), and use `transform` instead of `apply`, like this.

```
df['people'] = df.groupby(['id'])['value'].transform(lambda x: 1. / len(x))
```

The reason this didn't work while your first did is that your function returns a single value, rather than an array of values, so `transform` broadcasts back to the original frame's shape, while `apply` is more flexible and generally passes back whatever shape your function returns.